# android studio could not find android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3?

Tags: android

Error:(25) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Side-Menu.Android-master'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android-reporting']
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

```
  > A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.

     > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':library:_debugCompile'.

        > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.

          Searched in the following locations:

              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom

              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar

          Required by:

              com.yalantis:library:1.0
```

first time to use android studio and met the problem with this, help me !

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file for the `library` module.

Comment: Make sure you have the `Android Support Library` installed in the SDK Manager.